# jquery function doesn't work when called from usercontrol

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have an aspx page which holds 2 user controls

UC1: Edit page - this has the fields for editing or data entry.

UC2: Notification page - this has a simple message box with jquery function

in my aspx i have this function:

```
public void ShowMessage(string status, string message)
    {
        Notification1.Message = message; //this is my user control UC2
        Notification1.Status = status;
        Notification1.DataBind();
    }
```

now when my aspx page needs to show a message this works fine, but when i want the user control 1 to show a message like (invalid field, or wrong amount) it doesn't do anything.  Now it gets called but jquery just doesn't react to it.

in UC2 -notification user control this is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMsg(classname) {
    $("#MsgBox").attr('class', classname);
    $("#MsgBox").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
}
</script>
<div id="MsgBox" class="info"><asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" /></div>
```

codebehind

```
 public string Status{ get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public override void DataBind()
    {
        if (Message != string.Empty)
        {

            lblMessage.Text = Message;
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "showMsg('" + Status + "');", true);
        }

    }
```

and this is how i call the function from user control to aspx page:

```
((myaspxpage)this.Page).ShowMessage("error", "This is my error message.");
```

any help will be much appreciated! and if further details is needed just let me know.. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: I tried putting the jquery and message box inside my Edit page to see if it would work that way and it doesn't So it seems that jquery is not working well within a usercontrol??

Comment: Have you confirmed your jquery source is being found?

Comment: @Jeff i don't get any errors in my console in Chrome usually if it doesn't find the source then it tells you right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error is what that my button that was calling the function in aspx page was inside an update panel and i needed to add a trigger event to make it work.. Thanks everybody for the help it was that update panel causing the error :(

Answer (score 0):

Move your codes of `DataBind()` method into `OnPreRender`. This should work. The reason is that you don't know which code from which step of your page cycle (init, load, bind, ...) is going to change the `Message` property.

Like in your case it seems you have a button click event where you are setting the `Message` property from. This is too late because your `Notification1` control is already databound.

Leaving it as the latest stage makes it work:

```
protected override void OnPreRender()
    {
        if (Message != string.Empty)
        {

            lblMessage.Text = Message;
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "showMsg('" + Status + "');", true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I will try it, and let you know. Thanks

Comment: it still won't show, it gets called and goes through the process correctly but it just won't display..and when i check the html there nothing in the Message label..